# Persisting hasMany assoc in emberdata

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Any examples of persisting new model entity with hasMany associacion?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/vuT2v/

```
App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
    text: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    comments: DS.hasMany('App.Comment')
});

var first = App.Comment.createRecord({
    id: 'firstComment',
    text: 'first comment'
});
var second = App.Comment.createRecord({
    id: 'secondComment',
    text: 'second comment'
});

var post = App.Post.createRecord({
    id: 1,
    title: 'post title'
});

var comments = post.get('comments');
comments.addObject(first);
comments.addObject(second);

App.store.commit();​
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to update this objects... and the default implementation RESTAdapter do it like this:


`this.sideload(store, type, json, root);`
`store.didCreateRecord(model, json[root]);`

and it's make strange POST and GET request for children elements. in other words - i need to update ids for created elements